# I want to declare several buttons as one

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to make one declaration from b0 to b10 instead of b0 entering if.
/ How can I change several buttons to one declaration without using or?

```
b0 = tk.Button(root, text = (out0), bg=random.choice(color), command=lambda:code(out0))
b1 = tk.Button(root, text = (out1), bg=random.choice(color), command=lambda:code(out1))
b2 = tk.Button(root, text = (out2), bg=random.choice(color), command=lambda:code(out2))
b3 = tk.Button(root, text = (out3), bg=random.choice(color), command=lambda:code(out3))
b4 = tk.Button(root, text = (out4), bg=random.choice(color), command=lambda:code(out4))
b5 = tk.Button(root, text = (out5), bg=random.choice(color), command=lambda:code(out5))
b6 = tk.Button(root, text = (out6), bg=random.choice(color), command=lambda:code(out6))
b7 = tk.Button(root, text = (out7), bg=random.choice(color), command=lambda:code(out7))
b8 = tk.Button(root, text = (out8), bg=random.choice(color), command=lambda:code(out8))
b10 = tk.Button(root, text = (out9), bg=random.choice(color), command=lambda:code(out9)

if b0['bg'] == 'red':
      pin = pin[:-1]
```

Comment: why are you asking the same question over and over again? what is going on??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
buttons = []
for i in range(11):
    buttons.append( tk.Button(root, text = ('out'+str(i)), bg=random.choice(color), command=lambda:code(i))
if b[0]['bg'] == 'red':
      pin = pin[:-1]
```

Now `buttons` is a list with button i at index i. You just have to rewrite your command `code(out1)` for example to take `i` as input instead of `out1`.

Answer (score 0):

See classes in python !
class button(self):
   and here you put your code about buttons
This is really helpful because you can put more arguments than just self, and then call button(arguments) to create a new button !